# Getting all methods in class (not getting method in extend class)

Tags: java

Hello I want to get all methods in class that extends class2(abstract class), but it also gets method in class2

for example,

```
public static boolean hasClickedPlayerMethod(Ability ability) {
        for (Method method : ability.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if (!method.getName().equals("activeSkill")) continue;
            System.out.println(method); // returns activeSkill(Player clickedPlayer), activeSkill()
        }
        return false;
    }

// abstract class Ability

public boolean activeSkill() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean activeSkill(Player clickedPlayer) {
        return false;
    }

// Class BoatMan extends Ability

public BoatMan(Player player) {
        super(...)
    }

    public boolean activeSkill() {
}
...
```

In this, I want to get only
`public boolean activeSkill() {`
but it also gets `public boolean activeSkill(Player player) {`
how can I get only `public boolean activeSkill() {`? (BoatMan class has only `public boolean activeSkill() {` but extend class has `public boolean activeSkill(Player) {`

Comment: Why do you want to get the methods? What are you doing with it afterwards? Usually reflection is not the correct solution.

Comment: You can use `getParameterCount()` and `getParameterTypes`()`, but maybe you want to use interfaces instead of reflection.

Comment: As @Code-Apprentice already hinted at: this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ability.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()
```

getDeclaredMethods: "Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, but excluding inherited methods."